# Импорты в js и ts

Tags: javascript, typescript

Импортирую библиотеку на js так:

```
var Bot = require('bots');
```

И программа запускается.

Импортирую ту же самую библиотеку на ts так:

```
import Bot from 'bots';
```

и получаю ошибку

```
TypeError: bots_1.default is not a constructor
```

И задался вопросом, в чем же разница?

Comment: что за библиотека? в коде есть только строчка импорта? или падает при попытке использовать `Bot`?

Comment: Скорее всего нет дефолтного экспорта в библиотеке. Попробуй сделать так import { Bot } from 'bots'; или же import * as Bot from 'bots';

Comment: @1ocke спасибо, через import * as Bot from 'bots' получилось, но в чем же разница была?

Comment: @RuslanGorbunov надо смотреть на библиотеку) разница в экспорте

Comment: `import * as Bot from 'bots';`

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/search/?query=import&type=article